# jquery form validation (combine methods)

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am validating the form in different conditions, When form is submitted or changed or blur or key up/down. Example here...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // on submit
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $($(this)).validate();
    });

    // on change or blur
    $('form').change(function() {
        $($(this)).validate();
    });

    // on key up/down
    $('form').keyup(function() {
        $($(this)).validate();
    });
});
```

Just curious to know is there a way something like this...

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // on submit
    $('form').action('submit, change, keyup, keydown, blur', function() {
        $($(this)).validate();
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could be $('form').on(events): events One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin", or events-map [JQUERY](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Check out [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/) also, it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `on()`:

```
$('form').on('keyup change focus blur', function(){ ... })
```